# Watch form validity from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form within my controller. I'd like to be able to set a scope variable based on the validity of this form. I've given the form a name already:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    ...

    <form name='myForm'>
        ...
    </form>

    ...

</div>
```

And have created a $watch on that form's $valid property (this is located in the controller which contains this form):

```
$scope.$watch('myForm.$valid', function(oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log("Woo! This might be working!");
    if (newVal) {
        $scope.otherVar = true;
    } else {
        $scope.otherVar = false;
    }
}
```

My log statement ONLY appears on page load, but not when the form's validity changes. (I've verified that the form's $valid property is changing by inserting:

{{ myForm.$valid }}

within the scope of my form)

I've been looking around SO and from what I've seen this *should* be working. (Obviously something is wrong though...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is `function(oldVal, newVal)` should be `function(newVal, oldVal)`.
Apart from that I can't find any fault in your code.
Here's a working plunkr example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ur42HFcVQbpTEBkRBtdY?p=preview

Outside of that it's probably something else in your code affecting the form, you don't have it nested in something like an `ng-if` or `ng-view`?