# Angular watch form input doesnt work

Tags: angularjs

I have a form in html page :

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl as c">
      <form name="myForm">
        <input type="text" name="myInput" require/>
     </form>
</div>
```

I want to watch changes of input in my controller, so I did like this :

```
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', ctrl);
ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function ctrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.$watch('myForm.myInput', function (value) {
       //check validity
    });
}
```

But when I change input value, nothing happen in controller.
Any idea?

Comment: asisgn a model to input but anyway you don't want to check the input value validations by watching a model, there are more clear way to detect the input is clear  or not.

Comment: You code requires two changes only one is to add ng-model="c.myInput" and second one is to keep watching this property as i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @BrMe did you find the solution?

Comment: but if I want to check input validity , like this :  $scope.$watch('myForm.myInput,$valid', function (value) {
       //check validity
    });, watch the model is not enogh for me

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope.watch()` function creates a watch of some variable.

So you need to bind a scope to your input and creates watch for that variable.

View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myInput" name="myInput" require/>
```

Controller:

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.myInput = "";
    scope.$watch('myInput', function(newValue, oldValue) {
       // Your logic
    });

}
```

I believe watching the entire form may create a performance hit, still they are ways to watch multiple variable using watch

**1.** Create a $scope object like

```
     $scope.form = {
             name:"My Name",
             Id:"My Id:,
             ....
       }
```

Now you can use `$watch` with a third variable 'true'

```
    $scope.$watch('form', function(newVal, oldVal){
       console.log('changed');
     }, true);
```

Html:

```
         <input type="text" ng-model="form.name" name="myName" require/>
         <input type="text" ng-model="form.id" name="myId" require/>
```

**2.** Use  `$scope.$watchCollection`

```
       $scope.$watchCollection('[item1, item2]', function(newValues, oldValues){
         // You logic here
        // newValues and oldValues contain the new and old value  of the array      
        });
```

Also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952579/watch-multiple-scope-attributes) for different ways of listening changes to multiple elements using `$watch`

Comment: if I want to wacth all form? or check form validation? like :$scope.$watch('myForm.$valid', function (validity) { }); Can i do it?

Comment: I dont want to create form in controller' just to watch the form which exist on html, finally I check form validaion on ng-change of input. 10x anyway

Comment: 10x again..I think I can watch form like in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027876/watch-form-validity-from-parent-controller but it doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl as c">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myInput" ng-model="c.myInput" require/>
 </form>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function ctrl($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.myInput = 'hello';
  $scope.$watch(function(){
       return vm.myInput;
     }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(newValue)
  });

}
```